# What is the proper way to implement XGBoost external memory?

Tags: xgboost, python-3.8

I'm trying to use XGBoost on a dataset that is larger than the available memory. XGB has a feature where you can define your own data loader (described here https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/external_memory.html)

It seems fairly straightforward, but I am having trouble implementing it. Basically you need to define a class that has a next and reset method that gets passed to the DMatrix constructor. The next method also needs to take a callable as an input.

Naturally this seems like a good fit to use a series of generators that iterate over the files and chunk them.

**XGBoost Example**

```
import os
from typing import List, Callable
import xgboost
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file

class Iterator(xgboost.DataIter):
  def __init__(self, svm_file_paths: List[str]):
    self._file_paths = svm_file_paths
    self._it = 0
    # XGBoost will generate some cache files under current directory with the prefix
    # "cache"
    super().__init__(cache_prefix=os.path.join(".", "cache"))

  def next(self, input_data: Callable):
    """Advance the iterator by 1 step and pass the data to XGBoost.  This function is
    called by XGBoost during the construction of ``DMatrix``

    """
    if self._it == len(self._file_paths):
      # return 0 to let XGBoost know this is the end of iteration
      return 0

    # input_data is a function passed in by XGBoost who has the exact same signature of
    # ``DMatrix``
    X, y = load_svmlight_file(self._file_paths[self._it])
    input_data(X, y)
    self._it += 1
    # Return 1 to let XGBoost know we haven't seen all the files yet.
    return 1

  def reset(self):
    """Reset the iterator to its beginning"""
    self._it = 0

it = Iterator(["file_0.svm", "file_1.svm", "file_2.svm"])
Xy = xgboost.DMatrix(it)

# Other tree methods including ``hist`` and ``gpu_hist`` also work, but has some caveats
# as noted in following sections.
booster = xgboost.train({"tree_method": "approx"}, Xy)
```

**My Implementation**

```
class data_loader(xgb.DataIter):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.chunks = self.generate_data()
    
    def generate_data(self):
        for FILE in Path(DIR).glob('*csv'):
            for df in pd.read_csv(FILE,chunksize=100000):
                x = df[conf["simple_dims"]].values
                y = df[conf["metrics"]].values
                yield x,y

    def reset(self):
        self.chunks = self.generate_data()

    def next(self,input_data:callable):
        try:
            x,y = self.chunks.__next__()
            input_data(x,y)
        except:
            pass
        return 1 if any(self.chunks) else 0
```

I receive an error stating that my feature names are not unique when calling the DMatrix constructor. I've triple-checked my feature names and even tried passing a single feature and received the same error.